# Nodejitsu + HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, websocket, nodejitsu

When I go to https://myapp.nodejitsu.com I magically have ssl enabled. But my app's websocket transport seems to be broken now. What do I need to do to enable websockets over this https, what else could be broken? What are they doing to enable SSL?

Answer (score 3):

Nodejitsu uses [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to proxy https to http, to your app. The proxy supports websockets in both http and https modes. So, as long as your app can talk websockets over http, it should be fine.

I'd recommend shooting us an email at support@nodejitsu.com with the details.

--Josh