# Nodejitsu SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, nodejitsu

Does anyone knows how to deploy an SSL certificate to my nodejitsu App?

I can see that I already have https enabled but i would like to buy a SSL Certificate now that I'm opening for business.

Answer (score 4):

To get an SSL certificate working with a custom domain on Nodejitsu, you can do the following:

1. Subscribe to a ["business" plan on Nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/paas/pricing/#business) (custom domain + SSL isn't available for "individual" plans).
2. [Set up your DNS](https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/features/dns/) to use your domain.
3. Create a certificate signing request (CSR), [maybe by using OpenSSL like this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/csr).
4. Buy your SSL certificate from your certificate authority (CA) of choice.
5. Go to your Nodejitsu webops panel, where there is an SSL tab for your app.
6. Upload your private key (created with your CSR), your certificate, and your CA certificate, via the webops panel.

The details of these steps will be slightly different depending on what you use to create your CSR and who your cert provider is. If you get stuck [Nodejitsu support](https://www.nodejitsu.com/support/) can help set you up.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Where `cert.pem` should be the path to your certificate and `key.pem` should be the path to its private key

http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server

Comment: I had already read that, doesn't that affects how the proxy works?

Comment: I mean it already works, just without the certificate as noticed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748881/nodejitsu-https/11749884#11749884

Answer (score 1):

Drop us a line to support@nodejitsu.com or visit us on IRC at #nodejitsu in Freenode ([http://webchat.jit.su](http://webchat.jit.su/)) and we will help you with the configuration of the custom ssl certificate.

Comment: It's such a shame SSL is thought as a business-specific thing but not a security measure. I think some  agencies have a big part in forcing the policy of no SSL on free hosts. It's harder to force someone to backdoor his server if you don't know neither his name nor his credit card number.